# URL hash detect with safari browser and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, safari

I wrote a code for detect url and then making action. but its not working with safari browser(just reloading continiously). but it is working with chrome.

Here is the snippet:

```
<script>
var url      = window.location.href;
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#ok") == -1){
window.location.replace("http://myurl.com/locations/?wptouch_switch=desktop#ok");
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It dosen't seem to work with chrome as well:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("#ok") == -1)
{
console.log("OK DOES NOT EXIST REDIRECTING NOW");
        window.location.replace("http://myurl.com/locations/wptouch_switch=desktop#ok");
}
else
{
    console.log("OK exists");
}
```

This is the code you should use.

**OR BETTER STILL**

Try using window.location.hash :

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "#ok")
{
    console.log("OK exists");
}
else
{
    console.log("OK DOES NOT EXIST REDIRECTING NOW");
window.location.replace("http://myurl.com/locations/wptouch_switch=desktop#ok");
}
```